# db.SaveChanges always gives the following :The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Why when ever i call

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

i git this error

```
The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects
```

after debugging i noticed that the issue occurs when i call `getX()` function  inside my model :

```
public ICollection<Dish> getX()
        {
            if (this.x== null)
            {
                return x= this.initX().ToList<X>();
            }
            return x;
        }
```

while the `initX` is a simple `linq` query

**why i cant set the value of x?** so when i change the line to

```
return this.initX().ToList<X>(); // whithout x=...
```

it works fine ...

Comment: Just to be sure: you _only_ create a `DB` instance, call `SaveChanges()` and bang!, exception? The is no Database initializer involved?

Comment: @GertArnold yes for debugging I removed everything i've put the save statement as the start of the action i only make `restaurant = db.Restaurant.First();` at the OnActionExecuting function ...

Comment: @GertArnold can you check the update...

Comment: Is `getX()` inside an entity class? What is the code of `initX()`?

Comment: @GertArnold thanks alot ! the issue was there i used an instance of DB other than the on in the controller ,... thanks man for your time ... thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the same instance of the `ObjectContext` for all the querys on this transaction.